# Auto-Scrolling A Flexbox Column With A Sticky NavBar

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, sticky, tailwind-css

As this issue is easiest to explain with an example, here's a CodeSandbox to illustrate: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/metal450/react-scroll-sticky. The project is built in React, TailwindCSS, & [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) to do the smooth scrolling.

I'm trying to create links to scroll a column/row in a flexbox, with a sticky navbar.  It works great as long as the navbar is 'sticky' relative to the Flexbox's main axis, not its cross axis.  In the CodeSandbox, if the output is suitably wide (aka on large devices), you'll see that the sidebar appears on the left, & each link scrolls the column on the right, lining up its corresponding item with the top of the container.

However, if you shrink the output a bit until you see the 'small device' layout, you'll be able to see the issue.  Now that the 'sidebar' is at the top, if you click the nav buttons, it will scroll so that the selected item is hidden behind the nav bar.

This does makes some sense: the scroller scrolls relative to a container, and the top of that container is behind the sticky navbar.  However, my desired outcome is to click 'item 1' and have it scroll so that item 1 is at the top of the *scrollable area* (not hidden below the sticky navbar).

I'm fairly new to flexboxes, & no matter what I try, I can't seem to figure out the desired behavior.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @YellowAfterlife's answer, I'd use refs instead of `document.getElementById`.

Also, you only want the offset on "mobile" so you could use a package like `react-responsive` for that.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";

function App() {
  const items = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7"];
  const container = "scrollContainer";

  const menuRef = useRef(null);
  const [menuHeight, setMenuHeight] = useState(0);

  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({
    query: "(max-width: 767px)"
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setMenuHeight(menuRef.current.clientHeight);
  }, [menuRef]);

  return (
    <main className="flex absolute right-0 bottom-0 left-0 top-0">
      <div
        id={container}
        className="md:flex-row flex flex-col overflow-auto border border-box"
        style={{ flexBasis: "65%", flex: 2 }}
      >
        <div
          ref={menuRef}
          className="md:w-64 p-3 border sticky top-0 flex-shrink-0 bg-white border-box"
        >
          {items.map((item) => (
            <div className="cursor-pointer m-2 underline" key={item}>
              <Link
                to={item}
                smooth={true}
                duration={500}
                spy={true}
                containerId={container}
                offset={isMobile ? -menuHeight : null}
              >
                {item}
              </Link>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

        <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <div key={item} id={item} className="h-64 border m-2 bg-gray-100">
              {item}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-shape-o6cr0)

Comment: Great solution!  I didn't know about react-responsive, definitely handy to have in my toolbox :)  One question: what's the benefit of using useEffect w/ a menuRef to put clientHeight in a state variable, rather than just referring to menuRef.clientHeight.clientHeight directly when you scroll?

Comment: I ended up doing something like: `function getScrollOffset() {  if (window.getComputedStyle(menuRef.current?.parentElement).flexDirection === 'column') return -menuRef.current?.clientHeight || 0;
        return -gymCardOffset;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

`react-scroll` [supports](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll#propsoptions) `offset` argument, which you can use to dynamically account for menu height:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-scroll';

function App() {

    const items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7'];
    const container = "scrollContainer";
    const menu = "scrollMenu";

    function getScrollOffset() {
        if (true/* insert a condition for navbar being on top */) {
            return -document.getElementById(menu).offsetHeight;
        } else return 0;
    }

    return (
        <main className="flex absolute right-0 bottom-0 left-0 top-0">

            <div id={container} className="md:flex-row flex flex-col overflow-auto border border-box" style={{ flexBasis: "65%", flex: 2}}>

                <div className="md:w-64 p-3 border sticky top-0 flex-shrink-0 bg-white border-box" id={menu}>
                    {items.map((item) => <div className="cursor-pointer m-2 underline" key={item}>
                        <Link to={item} smooth={true} duration={500} spy={true} offset={getScrollOffset()} containerId={container}>{item}</Link>
                    </div>)}
                </div>

                <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    {items.map((item) => <div key={item} id={item} className="h-64 border m-2 bg-gray-100" >{item}</div>)}
                </div>

            </div>

        </main>
    );
}

export default App;
```

A CSS-only solution would be far less elegant and offer no particular benefit given that scrolling is already being handled by JavaScript side.

Comment: I thought of doing it that way, but it felt like that was more hacky & I was probably just overlooking the 'right' CSS-only approach (again being not that experienced with flexboxes).  If the CSS-only way is actually less elegant as you say tho, then maybe my first thought was actually the right approach!

Comment: ...Actually, it looks like that still has a peculiarity.  After clicking a scroll button, just mouseover the browser's scrollbar - suddenly the current scroll position indicator 'jumps' to a different position.  aka the browser thinks it's scrolled to a certain location, then when you mouseover its scrollbar, it changes.  Let me know if this is unlcear or if you don't see it, I'll post a video.

Comment: I don't think I'm seeing this on Edge 91 - the scrollbar appears to work as intended while animating and afterwards

Comment: Interesting.  I'm on Firefox 84 on Linux, & the scrollbar is definitely behaving screwy. In 'large device mode' it's predictable, but in 'small mode' (aka the topic of this issue), whether or not I use the offset, the scrollbar jumps around in an odd way, which makes it look buggy.